# Qt ffmpeg многоканальный стрим видео

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, ffmpeg

Всем доброго времени суток,
столкнулся с такой проблемой, в приложении получаю данные с камер в виде кадров, пытаюсь реализовать многоканальный стрим изображений через rtsp, на каждый канал выделяю отдельную функцию для стрима с разными названиями каналов и разными портами, в результате все изображения попадают в один стрим, в следствии чего отображается каша. каналы воспроизвожу при помощи ffplay
функция для стрима

```
AVCodecID codecID    = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
AVCodec* codec;
AVCodecContext* codecCtx;
AVPixelFormat pixfmt = AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8;
codec    = avcodec_find_encoder(codecID);
codecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);  
codecCtx->width         = HorFrameSize;
codecCtx->height        = VerFrameSize;
//codecCtx->time_base = (AVRational ) { 1, 25 };
codecCtx->time_base.num = 1;
codecCtx->time_base.den = 25;
codecCtx->gop_size      = 25;
codecCtx->max_b_frames  = -1;
codecCtx->pix_fmt       = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
codecCtx->codec_type    = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

if (codecID == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
{
    av_opt_set(codecCtx->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    av_opt_set(codecCtx->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
}

avcodec_open2(codecCtx, codec, NULL);

//Init the Frame containing our raw data
AVFrame* frame;

frame         = av_frame_alloc();

frame->format   = pixfmt;
frame->width  = codecCtx->width;
frame->height = codecCtx->height;
av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, frame->width, frame->height, codecCtx->pix_fmt,32);

//Init the format context
AVFormatContext* fmtCtx  = avformat_alloc_context();
AVOutputFormat*  format  = av_guess_format("rtsp", NULL, NULL);
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&fmtCtx, format, format->name, "rtsp://192.168.138.102:8550/0");

avio_open(&fmtCtx->pb, fmtCtx->filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);

//Configure the AVStream for the output format context
struct AVStream* stream      = avformat_new_stream(fmtCtx, codec);

avcodec_parameters_from_context(stream->codecpar, codecCtx);
stream->time_base.num        = 1;
stream->time_base.den        = 25;

/* Rewrite the header */
avformat_write_header(fmtCtx, NULL);

SwsContext * ctx = sws_getContext(HorFrameSize, VerFrameSize, pixfmt, HorFrameSize, VerFrameSize,AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 0, 0, 0, 0);

QImage image ;
AVPacket pkt;
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; ; i++)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    //av_read_frame (fmtCtx,&pkt);
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
    pkt.size = 0;


    image.loadFromData ((const uchar*)Image,(int)ImageSize);
    uint8_t* rgbData = image.bits();
    uint8_t * inData[1] = { rgbData }; // RGB24 have one plane
    int inLinesize[1] = { HorFrameSize }; // RGB stride

    sws_scale(ctx, inData, inLinesize, 0, VerFrameSize, frame->data, frame->linesize);

    /* Which frame is it ? */
    frame->pts = i;

    /* Send the frame to the codec */
    avcodec_send_frame(codecCtx, frame);

    /* Use the data in the codec to the AVPacket */
    switch(avcodec_receive_packet(codecCtx, &pkt))
    {
        case AVERROR_EOF:
            qDebug()<<"Stream EOF\n";
            break;

        case AVERROR(EAGAIN):
            qDebug()<<"Stream EAGAIN\n";
            break;

        default:

            printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", j++, pkt.size);
            av_packet_rescale_ts(&pkt, codecCtx->time_base, stream->time_base);
            /* Write the data on the packet to the output format  */
            av_interleaved_write_frame(fmtCtx, &pkt);

            /* Reset the packet */
            av_packet_unref(&pkt);
            break;
    }

    usleep(1e6/25);
}

// end
avcodec_send_frame(codecCtx, NULL);

//Free everything
av_free(codecCtx);
av_free(fmtCtx);
```

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Я так понимаю это не весь код? Каждая функция работает в отдельном потоке?

Comment: да, в отдельном. по функциям меняется только номер и порт канала. от получателя через if...else данные отправляются в разные потоки согласно идентификатора канала

Comment: Возможно надо с инициализровать ffmpeg для каждого потока отдельно. Но это стоит уточнить в документации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как оказалось, все данные с разных камер писались в один адрес памяти, что и приводило к смешиванию кадров